# Features View, directory browsing hide and seek

Tags: iis-7

In Microsoft Windows 7, IIS, features view tab, I don't see "directory browsing".
How do I make this view visible?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Install the feature from Control Panel.

Go to Control Panel, Programs and Features, Turn Windows Features On or Off, and check `Internet Information Services` / `World Wide Web Services` / `Common HTTP Features`  /`Directory Browsing`